# Diamond inheritence problem

Tags: inheritance, solidity

```
interface I { }

contract A is I { }

contract B is A { }

contract C is A { }

contract D is B, C { }
```

What would happen in this situation? How is this kind of diamond inheritance resolved in solidity? Should I be aware of any "gotchas"?

Answer (score 0):

From [the docs](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/contracts.html#multiple-inheritance-and-linearization): The order in which the base classes are listed matters. `C` will override `B` to the extent they share content in common.

For 'gotchas:' If there are multiple different kinds of functions with the same name, an error might be produced; details are [here](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/contracts.html#inheriting-different-kinds-of-members-of-the-same-name) (reposted in part under [GPL](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/blob/develop/LICENSE.txt)):

> When the inheritance results in a contract with a function and a modifier of the same name, it is considered as an error. This error is produced also by an event and a modifier of the same name, and a function and an event of the same name. As an exception, a state variable getter can override a public function.